# Moving a CakePHP 1.3.2 Application to a New Server

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a very old CakePHP 1.3.2 application that used to work on a server under a given domain. I have the original files and now I'm trying to set it up and get it running on a new server under a different domain.

At first I had to fix the following line in the webroot/index.php:

```
define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', '/home/SOME_NAME/cakephp-1.3.2');
```

as the application could not even find the framework. It does find it now but I'm getting a `404 Page Not Found` error. I'm completely clueless what is causing it and I even can't determine if the database connection is successful using the new user/pass/host parameters. The only indication of something going on is the following log file that I found on the server and it gets populated with the following lines every time I try to access the application through the browser:

```
2015-06-09 10:00:24 Warning: Warning (512): /home/SOME_NAME/public_html/OLD_DOMAIN_NAME/tmp/cache/ is not writable in [/home/SOME_NAME/cakephp-1.3.2/cake/libs/cache/file.php, line 267]
2015-06-09 10:00:24 Warning: Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in [/home/SOME_NAME/cakephp-1.3.2/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php, line 127]
2015-06-09 10:00:24 Warning: Warning (2): array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in [/home/SOME_NAME/cakephp-1.3.2/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 1936]
2015-06-09 10:00:24 Warning: Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in [/home/SOME_NAME/cakephp-1.3.2/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php, line 127]
2015-06-09 10:00:24 Warning: Warning (2): array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in [/home/SOME_NAME/cakephp-1.3.2/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 1949]
2015-06-09 10:00:24 Warning: Warning (2): array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in [/home/SOME_NAME/cakephp-1.3.2/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 1953]
2015-06-09 10:00:24 Warning: Warning (2): array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in [/home/SOME_NAME/cakephp-1.3.2/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 1953]
2015-06-09 10:00:24 Warning: Warning (2): array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in [/home/SOME_NAME/cakephp-1.3.2/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 2045]
2015-06-09 10:00:24 Warning: Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in [/home/SOME_NAME/cakephp-1.3.2/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php, line 127]
2015-06-09 10:00:24 Warning: Warning (2): array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in [/home/SOME_NAME/cakephp-1.3.2/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 1936]
2015-06-09 10:00:24 Warning: Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in [/home/SOME_NAME/cakephp-1.3.2/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php, line 127]
2015-06-09 10:00:24 Warning: Warning (2): array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in [/home/SOME_NAME/cakephp-1.3.2/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 1949]
2015-06-09 10:00:24 Warning: Warning (2): array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in [/home/SOME_NAME/cakephp-1.3.2/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 1953]
2015-06-09 10:00:24 Warning: Warning (2): array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in [/home/SOME_NAME/cakephp-1.3.2/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 1953]
2015-06-09 10:00:24 Warning: Warning (2): array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in [/home/SOME_NAME/cakephp-1.3.2/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 2045]
2015-06-09 10:00:24 Warning: Warning (2): array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in [/home/SOME_NAME/cakephp-1.3.2/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 1229]
2015-06-09 10:00:24 Warning: Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in [/home/SOME_NAME/cakephp-1.3.2/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php, line 127]
2015-06-09 10:00:24 Warning: Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in [/home/SOME_NAME/cakephp-1.3.2/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php, line 127]
2015-06-09 10:00:24 Warning: Warning (2): implode() [<a href='function.implode'>function.implode</a>]: Invalid arguments passed in [/home/SOME_NAME/cakephp-1.3.2/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 1448]
2015-06-09 10:00:24 Warning: Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in [/home/SOME_NAME/cakephp-1.3.2/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php, line 127]
2015-06-09 10:00:24 Warning: Warning (2): array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in [/home/SOME_NAME/cakephp-1.3.2/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 1936]
2015-06-09 10:00:24 Warning: Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in [/home/SOME_NAME/cakephp-1.3.2/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php, line 127]
2015-06-09 10:00:24 Warning: Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in [/home/SOME_NAME/cakephp-1.3.2/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php, line 127]
2015-06-09 10:00:24 Warning: Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in [/home/SOME_NAME/cakephp-1.3.2/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php, line 127]
2015-06-09 10:00:24 Warning: Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in [/home/SOME_NAME/cakephp-1.3.2/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php, line 127]
2015-06-09 10:00:24 Warning: Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in [/home/SOME_NAME/cakephp-1.3.2/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php, line 127]
2015-06-09 10:00:24 Warning: Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in [/home/SOME_NAME/cakephp-1.3.2/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php, line 127]
2015-06-09 10:00:24 Warning: Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in [/home/SOME_NAME/cakephp-1.3.2/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php, line 127]
2015-06-09 10:00:24 Warning: Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in [/home/SOME_NAME/cakephp-1.3.2/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php, line 127]
```

Any suggestions on how to proceed from here to narrow down the error to something more specific?

Comment: Have you tried searching the app's files for `OLD_DOMAIN_NAME`? It would appear there is a reference to it somewhere in your code and you need to change it.

Comment: The files on the new server are still in a folder OLD_DOMAIN_NAME so the path exists and the files are still there. I'll make a search though to see what else will pop up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first error is because `/home/SOME_NAME/public_html/OLD_DOMAIN_NAME/tmp/cache/` is not writeable. Make sure that `tmp` has the correct file permissions; it needs to be writeable by the web server user.

Otherwise your issue appears to be that the database config is wrong so the app cannot connect to the database. Check `app/config/database.php` and make sure the database is setup correctly and make sure that `bootstrap.php` isn't altering the connection (perhaps dependent on the server the app is installed).

You can check which database settings are being used in your code using:-

```
Configure::read('Session.database');
```

Test this near one of your errors.

If you can clear up those two issues you should be good.

Comment: The first one is cleared now, thank you. As for the database issue, it seems that it is setup correctly and I don't see anything in bootstrap.php that would alter the connection. Any ideas how to verify that it is working as intended?

Comment: Hm, might be irrelevant but I have the following two lines in the webroot/index.php:
$Dispatcher = new Dispatcher(); $Dispatcher->dispatch();
The error that I'm getting is generated after the call to dispatch().

Comment: The `Dispatcher` code is ok as that comes from Cake itself (https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.3/app/webroot/index.php). I've updated my answer with a suggestion about checking which database settings are in use. Still suspect this is the cause of your issue.

Comment: It does make sense but what I got from Configure::read(...); per your suggestion was just 'default'. I guess that knocks out bootstrap out of the picture at least. I've read somewhere that this might be caused by missing model so is there a way to check what exactly is causing the issue in more detailed error message? I've check the routes and the controller/model/view used there seem to be ok...

Comment: Cake's error logs should really be telling you if models are missing (`tmp/logs/error.log`). Your issue appears to arise from this line of code `$cols = $this->query('SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM ' . $this->fullTableName($model));` (https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.3/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php#L125) it might be worth checking what the query being generated is and whether it runs on your database (wouldn't normally recommend hacking core code, but may be the quickest way of reaching an answer).

Comment: So at the end it turns out that there were several tables missing from the database and it seems to be working now when they were added. What annoys me beyond boiling point though is that there was no human readable easy to understand message indicating that. I mean, come on, that should be one of the first errors that one could think of and it's not covered by the framework? Anyway, thank you very much for your time and dedication, marking this as correct as it was the database indeed and upvoting. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is an old version indeed but unfortunately I had no choice when a client decided to dig up a legacy project to run it again. Thanks again and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have your work cut out for you. For starters, I would create a phpinfo to see the configuration differences between the old and new servers.

```
<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

// Show just the module information.
// phpinfo(8) yields identical results.
phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);

?>
```

[phpinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)

Comment: I have no access to the old server. The site was live on it more than an year ago and now it's long gone.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you develop site locally or in a non-production environment. I would still run the phpinfo on the current server. I would also change/add the following settings in your php.ini file:   ini_set('display_errors',1);    
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);   
error_reporting(-1);

Comment: Also, do you have cakewalk configured on your current host? Does your current host support the use of cakewalk?